# Differential Equations Solve the initial Value problem $y' = -0.05 y + 25 ,y(0) = 80$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y' = -0.05 y + 25,
y(0) = 80$

Apparently the answer is
$y(t) =  -420e^{-0.05t} + 500$

I am not getting anything close to that. I am not sure the correct way to even begin this problem.

Obviously I don't need the answer, I want to understand how to do the problem.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Use method of undetermined coefficients, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients). Solve for the homogeneous part, $y_h$, and the inhomogeneous part, $y_p$, add together and _then_ apply your initial condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**: $y' + 0.05y = 25 \to (e^{0.05t}y)' = 25e^{0.05t}$. Can you continue?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

This DEQ can be solved using Separation of Variables and you will get:

$$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{dy}{-0.05 y + 25} = \int dx$$

I think you can continue.